# How can I access the WinRT default styles for MessageDialog Controls?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, styles, messagebox

While writing a windows store app I need to create a custom message dialog based on a popup (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593978/in-winrt-api-how-to-accept-user-input-in-a-dialog-just-like-in-weather-and-fina)). Usually [message dialogs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.popups.messagedialog.aspx) have a specific theme or style which depends on the system settings. I don't want to break the style of message dialogs, so I need to know how to reuse the system default style for message boxes, and especially buttons in message boxes.

So my question is as mentioned in the title: **How can I access the WinRT default styles for MessageDialog controls?**