# Windows.UI.Popups.ContentDialog Class for Windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I'm making a universal Windows app that uses the `Windows.UI.Popups.ContentDialog` class in the Windows Phone section.  What I need is that class for Windows (it is only supported in Windows Phone).  I can't seem to find anything about it, so I was wondering if any of you did.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's plenty of information available about this, see [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/2c7b290a-dd84-44a7-b3f4-29abc55fe010/how-to-show-dialog-with-textbox-control?forum=winappswithcsharp) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593978/in-winrt-api-how-to-accept-user-input-in-a-dialog-just-like-in-weather-and-fina).

There is no equivalent control available for Windows. You'll have to implement it yourself. You can use a Flyout.